Ubuntu 22.04 IPv6 accessible only from iOS
Hi I have the following issue on Ubuntu 22.04,
The PC is accessible from outside network only by iPhone (Chrome) using IPv6.
When I try the same from other Ubuntu or Mac computer I'm unable to access at all, I get the "host unreachable error" no matter is that through CLI or browser.
My intention is to use IPv6 because my current Cable operator doesn't allow IPv4 access, and hence I can access the PC from iOS using 5G network it means that ngnix is properly set (I can see the default html page).
My question is, how can I make this to work form other devices, what I'm missing?
When I type [2a02:810d:9840:5cc.......] from browser (except on iPhone) it returns not reachable, same applies using ping6 command.
Thanks

Guessing the network provider you have for your Ubuntu and Mac computers doesn't support IPv6. On the iPhone you're using data from your cell carrier to reach the server. If you turn off cell data on the iPhone, use only the WiFi for the network where your test Mac / Ubuntu machines live, can you reach the server then?

Please provide the full IP addresses of the server host, the PC, and the phone. Obscuring some of it prevents us from helping you, we cannot try to access it ourselves.   Also try  https://test-ipv6.com/  which will run several diagnostics, and from the Help Desk tab share the results url.

@tsc_chazz on iphone it doesn’t matter which network I use, it is accessible over 5G and few different wifi networks.

@JohnMahowald addresses are not shared due to security reasons. I’m not asking you to test them from your side, I’m asking for idea or tools that I can use to identify the issue. Thanks

Please provide a network diagram of how your  Linux, mac, and iPhone hosts are connected,  including host IPs, the routers and route tables where known. You can obfuscate with /48s out of the documentation prefix for your network and the ISPs network, but this is not ideal.   Providing your IP addresses has privacy concerns, but should not be a security problem.    Please also provide the test procedure you used, which browser or other user agent software, and from which device.
